# How to unsubscribe from Zendesk "How would you rate the support you received?" automated follow up emails?

Tags: zendesk

Is it possible to unsubscribe to Zendesk "How would you rate the support you received?" automated follow up emails, such as the screenshot below.

I get loads of these and i cant see a way that i can unsubscribe.

[image: screenshot of zendesk support email]

Answer (score 1):

Zendesk has this feature. Contact the company and point them to this article:

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203692166-Allow-Customers-To-Opt-Out-Of-Satisfaction-Questionaires

In the meantime, on your side, you can set up filters and redirect those emails elsewhere.